# Android manifest error when trying to make a facebook login application

Tags: android, facebook, compiler-errors, manifest

I'm trying to make an app that allows the user to login to facebook. I've followed the steps on developers.facebook.com thorougly but when I paste this block of code in the manifest I get the error bellow. (I am supposed to use this block of code according to their official tutorial.)

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute activity#com.facebook.FacebookActivity@theme value=(@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar) from AndroidManifest.xml:24:13-72
>       is also present at [com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.1] AndroidManifest.xml:32:13-63 value=(@style/com_facebook_activity_theme).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:21:9-25:48 to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`.